# In SwiftUI how can I assign variable in view?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this code here (placed in a view):

```swift
if videoPos > 0.05 {
                    Text("It Worked Yay!")
                    playerPaused = false
                }
```

However, since "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" I am not sure how I can change the variable when videoPos is > 0.05.

This is videoPos: `@Binding private(set) var videoPos: Double`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Update `playerPaused` where you update `videoPos`.

Comment: I have pasted where I directly declare and set videoPos equal to another value, here: https://pastebin.com/9zVr6geB but it isn't inside of the same struct (VideoPlayerControlsView) but in another class, how can I edit it from there?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez If it helps here is all my code: https://pastebin.com/Ss6m0CA1

Comment: You can use this ```}// Your view end
                .onChange(of: videoPos) { value in
                    playerPaused = false
                }```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use onChange

```
}// End HStack
.onChange(of: videoPos, perform: { value in
    if value > 0.05 {
        playerPaused = false
    }
})
```

if iOS 13 supported then use combine

```
}// End HStack
.onReceive(Just(videoPos), perform: { value in
    if value > 0.05 {
        playerPaused = false
    }
})
```

```
import Combine
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had spent so long trying to solve this :)